# How to get rid of program whose uninstall throws NSIS error?

Tags: windows-10, openvpn, uninstall, nsis

I installed [`OpenVPN 2.4.x`](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html) on `Windows 10` and the latest version was too unstable so I wanted to uninstall it to go back to a stable version. However, uninstalling it from both the the uninstall.exe that came with the install and `Control Panel` both resulted in `NSIS Error`:

[image]

How can I get rid of a program whose uninstall causes this error?

**UPDATE:**  I reinstalled it and retried the uninstall after the reinstall but still get the same outcome.

Comment: In order to solve this, you will need the same installer you originally used, do you have access to the OpenVPN 2.4.6 installer?

Comment: yes, I tried but couldn't

Comment: So does that mean you have access to the file?

Comment: Yes -- the original installer does not enable uninstalling

Comment: What are the contents of the installation directory?  The error is caused by a CRC check failure.  You can get around that by running the uninstaller with the /NCRC command option, in an elevated command prompt, or fix the integrity issue by reinstalling the same version then uninstall it normally.

Comment: There is no installation directory, just `openvpn-install-2.4.6-I602.exe`

Comment: Try *installing* the program (over itself) and then uninstalling.

Comment: If you don't have an OpenVPN installation directory, then OpenVPN wasn't uninstalled properly, install it again and run the uninstaller contained within the installation directory.

Comment: I installed it and reinstalled it and retried the uninstall after the reinstall -- same thing happens

Comment: @Ramhound was correct however want to spell it out so others understand. You need to make sure you program has an uninstall .exe. You need to go where the program is installed (Usually in "C:\Program Files" or "C:\Program Files (x86)", then look in the folder with another exe that would be used to uninstall. Then open CMD as admin, and run `"C:\Program Files\TheProgram\Uninstaller.exe" /NCRC`. THis will bypass the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a program called Revo Uninstaller, which may be of some help in this situation. It will try to run the original uninstaller, then go through a process to scan the Registry and hard drive for left over items.

You can find this program here: [Revo Uninstaller on download.cnet.com](https://download.cnet.com/s/revo-uninstaller/) .

Comment: While this at first looked like some sketchy hackware from China -- it actually worked !!

Comment: **It is sketchy hackware**.  You do more harm with then good with registry cleaners with shovelware like Revo Uninstaller.

Comment: @amphibient It has always worked for me, and I have never had any problems with it. On occasion, it has been the only product that worked.